# Forward service records from main DNS to IPA server

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, redhat, ldap, kerberos

I have a production DNS server (dns1.local) in Data Center environment, I build recently IPA server (ipa.example.com) that runs DNS as well in the same environment and it forwards requests to dns1.local, I want to configure an ipa client (ipaclient.example.com) in the same environment as well.

Now I am planning to keep dns1.local as the main DNS to the client, I want to add the below ipa service records in dns1.local to be served from IPA DNS:

```
_ldap._tcp              IN SRV 0 100 389        ipa

_kerberos               IN TXT EXAMPLE.COM

_kerberos._tcp          IN SRV 0 100 88         ipa

_kerberos._udp          IN SRV 0 100 88         ipa

_kerberos-master._tcp   IN SRV 0 100 88         ipa

_kerberos-master._udp   IN SRV 0 100 88         ipa

_kpasswd._tcp           IN SRV 0 100 464        ipa

_kpasswd._udp           IN SRV 0 100 464        ipa

_ntp._udp               IN SRV 0 100 123        ipa
```

In the above mentioned case ipa client will use dns1.local as the main DNS, in case the client required authentication or kerbors ticket dns1.local will forward this request to IPA DNS (ipa.example.com).

Can I implement the above? Any advise, I tried that but I still have a DNS issue, appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Red Hat has an extremely accurate documentation of their products. On your case at hand, please refer to https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Linux_Domain_Identity_Authentication_and_Policy_Guide/prerequisites.html#dns-reqs

If you are still experiencing troubles, pleas specify exactly what you have tried and what the results are, and try this in a (eventually virtualized) test environment, it should be quite trivial to achieve.

Comment: Not a bad link, link-only answers are susceptible to link rot and generally frowned upon. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/206620